# Are there any method to do the android reversing engineering with apk files that without file extensions？

Tags: python, android, reverse-engineering

I am working on malware detection for my paper and doing reverse engineering by androguard to get static analysis.I downloaded a few datasets from `http://contagiomobile.deependresearch.org/index.html`.

These files are “file” format without any filename extensions.

Some of these malware cannot be added “.apk” extension as they are recognized as virus on my windows.

So my question is are there any solutions that can do the reverse engineering right on these files without changing the filename extensions?

Comment: aren't APK files just ZIP files with a different extension?  Can you just upen the archive with 7-zip or some other utility?

Comment: I tried and failed. 7-zip says it cannot open file as archive. I guess the reason is the  file extension and I cannot change it since the Windows warns me. Should I allow the threats to add a file extension to continue the experiment? a little scared..

Comment: if z-zip does not open it, I don't think renaming it at this point would help.

Comment: I just turn off the windows security settings and it works.(sorry for this late reply